# Python sort values recorded in the same calendar date across multiple years

Tags: python, date, pandas, group-by, time-series

I am working on a dataframe that contain daily values recorded over a multi-year time span like this

```
   Date    Position  Value
2010-01-01 PEAK      60
2010-01-01 BOTTOM    51
2010-01-02 PEAK      62
2010-01-02 BOTTOM    50
...
2011-01-01 PEAK      70
2011-01-01 BOTTOM    61
2011-01-02 PEAK      72
2011-01-02 BOTTOM    60
...
2015-12-31 PEAK      92
2015-12-31 BOTTOM    83
```

That is, row entries corresponding to each calendar date are repeated for 6 years in a row, disregarding leap years (i.e., Feb. 29th) and i want to group them by calendar date regardless of years like the following format

```
       Date    Position  Value
    2010-01-01 PEAK      60
    2010-01-01 BOTTOM    51
    2011-01-01 PEAK      63
    2011-01-01 BOTTOM    57
    ...
    2015-01-01 PEAK      84
    2015-01-01 BOTTOM    71
    ...
    2014-12-31 PEAK      85
    2014-12-31 BOTTOM    79
    2015-12-31 PEAK      92
    2015-12-31 BOTTOM    83
```

What will be a better way to do such groupby() operation, suppose I want to maintain the leeway to do some simple calculation (e.g., max(), min(), mean()) on the values within each calendar date "group"?

I did check all relevant previous post but cannot seem to find an appropriate for my purpose here. I will really appreciate if someone could point out a better way to do this.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You have a sort issue to solve. One way is to do this with an intermediate dataframe:

```
df2 = pd.DataFrame([df.Date.dt.month, df.Date.dt.day]).T

df2.columns = [0,1]

df2
Out[32]: 
    0   1
0   1   1
1   1   1
2   1   2
3   1   2
4   1   1
5   1   1
6   1   2
7   1   2
8  12  31
9  12  31

df2 = df2.sort_values([0,1])
```

Now reindex `df` with the resulting index we have now in `df2`:

```
df.reindex(df2.index)
Out[36]: 
        Date Position  Value
0 2010-01-01     PEAK     60
1 2010-01-01   BOTTOM     51
4 2011-01-01     PEAK     70
5 2011-01-01   BOTTOM     61
2 2010-01-02     PEAK     62
3 2010-01-02   BOTTOM     50
6 2011-01-02     PEAK     72
7 2011-01-02   BOTTOM     60
8 2015-12-31     PEAK     92
9 2015-12-31   BOTTOM     83
```

Comment: Thanks a bunch. This is much tidier than the one I got. I will give it another try!

Answer (score 0):

IIUC you can do it this way:

```
In [2]: df
Out[2]:
        Date Position  Value
0 2010-01-01     PEAK     60
1 2010-01-01   BOTTOM     51
2 2010-01-02     PEAK     62
3 2010-01-02   BOTTOM     50
4 2011-01-01     PEAK     70
5 2011-01-01   BOTTOM     61
6 2011-01-02     PEAK     72
7 2011-01-02   BOTTOM     60
8 2015-12-31     PEAK     92
9 2015-12-31   BOTTOM     83

In [3]: df.groupby([df.Date.dt.month, df.Date.dt.day, 'Position']).agg(['min','mean','max','sum'])
Out[3]:
                   Value
                     min mean max  sum
Date Date Position
1    1    BOTTOM      51   56  61  112
          PEAK        60   65  70  130
     2    BOTTOM      50   55  60  110
          PEAK        62   67  72  134
12   31   BOTTOM      83   83  83   83
          PEAK        92   92  92   92
```

Comment: It works. I tried your method and converted the values into a list. I am now working on plotting these 365 values mapping them onto their respective calendar days. Thank you.